# Proof of stationary distribution of Finite Irreducible Markov Chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In reading the proof that a finite irreducible markov chain has a unique stationary distribution given by  $\pi_j = \frac{1}{u_j}$ where $\mu_j = E(T_j|X_0 = j)$ is the expected return time to $j$ for a chain starting in $j$, I am having a problem understanding it.

In the first part of the proof it proves that the proportion of the time spend in state j starting from state i in the long run is $\frac{1}{\mu_j}$ , that is :

\begin{gather*} 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m = 0}^{n-1}P_{ij}^m = \frac{1}{u_j}
\end{gather*}

Then the proof goes as follows :

To show $\pi$ is a stationary distribution we need to show that
\begin{gather*} 
\sum_{i = 1}^k\frac{1}{\mu_i}P_{ij} = \frac{1}{u_j}
\end{gather*}

We have that :

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{i = 1}^k\frac{1}{\mu_i}P_{ij} &= \sum_{i=1}^k\Bigl(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1}P_{ii}^m    \Bigr)P_{ij} \\
 & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{k}P_{ii}^mP_{ij} \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m = 0}^{n-1} P_{ij}^{m+1}\\
&= \text{The proof continous}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I don't understand how the equation three arises i.e $\sum_{i=1}^{k}P_{ii}^mP_{ij} = P_{ij}^{m+1}$. That is that a chain starting at $i$ reaches $i$ after $m$ steps that in the $m+1^{th}$ step goes to $j$ is equivalent to a chain starting at $i$ and going to $j$ in $m+1$ steps.

Please find entire proof here :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in the sum it uses the Fubinni-Tonelli theorem to interchange the two sums if that is your question or if i have clearly understood